# Using the Return Value of a Function to Select an Element in a Struct Array

Tags: matlab

I'm learning MATLAB (still trying to "think in vectors") and have the following piece of code:

```
stats = regionprops(bwconncomp(mask), 'all');

% find the object nearest our nucleus
smallest_dist = flintmax;
location = [cell_x, cell_y];
for j = 1:numel(stats)
    stat = stats(j);
    dist = pdist([location;[stat.Centroid]], 'euclidean');
    if dist < smallest_dist
        regions{channel} = stat; 
        smallest_dist = dist;
    end
end
```

All that is doing is searching through a struct array for the region which has a location (centroid) closest to my known cell's X/Y.  I'm sure this is not canonical and that it could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this comes pretty close. The use of arrayfun() or other *fun()-Operations is very often better than for loops.

Your code was not working out of the box. Thus, I created code, which is directly executable:

```
function minimalExample()
    target.x = 10;
    target.y = 5;

    source(1) = struct('x', 1, 'y', 3);
    source(2) = struct('x', 5, 'y', 15);

    [~, minIndex] = min(arrayfun(@(x) (myDistance(x, target)), source));

    minSource = source(minIndex);
    disp(minSource);

    function d = myDistance(source, target)
        d = (source.x - target.x)^2 + (source.y - target.y)^2;
        d = sqrt(d);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll accept it.  As it's been almost two weeks since posting I have learned mroe about MATLAB and changed this to use `arrayfun` myself (actually, I used `arrayfun` to implement `minby`, so it's now `minby(stats, @(s)(pdist([p, [s.Centroid]], 'euclidean')));`, which uses `find(x,'first')` internally).  Again though, thanks.

Comment: I just found this code review page. Great, you found *fun() already. There are millions of great applications for those and most of the time they are more readable than vectorized versions with a lot of reshape and repmat.

Comment: For the record: If performance is of interest: Arrayfun is horribly slow compared to normal `for`-loops in 99% of the cases.